# Javers IlegalArguementException

Tags: javers

Javers Team,
I am  Thomas and I am using  Javers 2.0.3 and  I am getting the below error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument should not be null
at org.javers.common.validation.Validate.argumentsAreNotNull(Validate.java:33)
at org.javers.core.JaversCore.compare(JaversCore.java:119)
```

Looks like it is not able to handle NULLS. I am using Javers to compare two Entity of same type `diff = javers.compare(oldEntity,newEntity);`
which has many entities defined inside having one to one, one to many relationships.

I read in another Stackflow post, this issue was resolved with 1.2.1.

JAVERS  Breaking with the above respective ERROR

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error, `IllegalArgumentException` means that you have put illegal data to compare() function. Both arguments have to be non-null.

Inside your domain objects you can have as many null as you need, but as the javadoc for compare() method says:

```
 * To calculate a diff, just provide two versions of the
 * same Domain Object (Entity or ValueObject)
 * or handles to two versions of the same object graph.
```